# Scala if-else chained with function call

Tags: scala

Why in the `condition2` case the behavior is not what I expected? Is there any link/reference which specifies such behavior?

Based on my understanding, in `condition2` case, the `.map(_ + 1)` combined with the `else{}`, while I expect the  `.map(_ + 1)` combined with the result of `if-else`

```
object Main {
  def main(args: Array[String]): Unit = {
    val condition: Boolean = true
    val a = if (condition) {
      Seq(1, 2, 3)
    } else {
      Seq(1, 2, 3)
    }

    val b = a.map(_ + 1)
    println(b) // Results in List(2, 3, 4)

    val condition2: Boolean = true
    val c = if (condition2) {
      Seq(1, 2, 3)
    } else {
      Seq(1, 2, 3)
    }.map(_ + 1)

    println(c) // Results in List(1,2,3), but I expect it to be List(2,3,4)

  val condition3: Boolean = false
  val d = if (condition3) {
    Seq(1, 2, 3)
  } else {
    Seq(1, 2, 3)
  }.map(_ + 1)

  println(d) // Results in List(2,3,4)
}
}
```

Thanks in advance for any help.

Answer (score 5):

Because Scala compiler treats `a` and `b` in `if (cond) a else b` construct as separate expressions, so in your case `a` is `Seq(1, 2, 3)` and `b` is `{Seq(1, 2, 3)}.map(_ + 1)` (i.e. everything after `else` is a separate expression). You can wrap `if-else` into parenthesis:

```
val c = (if (condition2) {
           Seq(1, 2, 3)
         } else {
           Seq(1, 2, 3)
         }).map(_ + 1)
```

And it will work as expected.

See also the [Conditional Expressions](https://www.scala-lang.org/files/archive/spec/2.13/06-expressions.html#conditional-expressions) specification for Scala 2.13.